# Kentico video not rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico

I'm trying to render a video using a custom transformation. I have the following transformation

```
        <video width="320" height="240" controls>
          <source src="<%# GetFileUrl('VideoFile') %>" type='video/mp4' >
        </video>
```

But this will display :"Too many characters in character literal".
Any idea this is happening?

Comment: Have you tried <%# GetFileUrl("VideoFile") %> ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to change it to the following:

```
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source src='<%# GetFileUrl("VideoFile") %>' type='video/mp4' >
    </video>
```

The `GetFileUrl` is taking the argument as a single character, also note the single quotes around the source attribute too.

Comment: @wale might be worth trying a clean/rebuild or clear cache. It seems to work for me.

Comment: I no longer get the error:"Too many characters in character literal" but video is still not rendering.

Comment: What does is render at this moment? Have you tried to render <%# Eval("VideoFile") %> to see if the field data is present?

Answer (score 0):

Here are few things that you can try:-

1. If you are uploading a video to a page type then you can directly access that URL using it's field name

   `<video width="320" height="240" controls>
       <source src="<%# Eval("VideoFile") %> type='video/mp4'>
   </video>`
2. Check your IIS settings if you server is able to serve files with MIME type video/mp4 and are not getting 404 error in browser developer's console. In your web.config file under `<staticContent>` tag check if you have this entry.

   `<mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />`